# R csv export with specific decimal places produces output with unwanted spaces

Tags: r, csv, decimal, write.table

After a couple of steps I am trying to export a csv file with given separators and decimal places in R.

I do calculations like:

```
Data_Table$`field_output` <- ifelse(Data_Table$`field_1` > 0, 
                                      Data_Table$`field_2`,
                                      Data_Table$`field_3`
                                     )
```

I tried two types of formatting:

```
Data_Table$`field_output` <- format(round(Data_Table$`field_output`, 2), nsmall = 2)
```

and

```
Data_Table$`field_output` <- formatC(Data_Table$`field_output`, digits=2, format="f")
```

then export:

```
write.table(Data_Table, file=paste("./output/filename_", datestring, ".csv"), quote=FALSE, sep=";", eol = "\n", dec=".", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)
```

My problem is the output

It produces right aligned columns with extra spaces/characters leading the output field

```
datestring;ID;UOM;field_output
20160831;1;kWh;100628610.00
20160831;2;kWh;  1800000.00
20160831;3;kWh;      252.00
20160831;4;kWh;        0.00
20160831;5;kWh;        0.00
```

Is there a way to get rid of those, and have a format like this:

```
datestring;ID;UOM;field_output
20160831;1;kWh;100628610.00
20160831;2;kWh;1800000.00
20160831;3;kWh;252.00
20160831;4;kWh;0.00
20160831;5;kWh;0.00
```

Thank you for your replies in advance! And excuse me if it's something trivial, or already answered!

Comment: Can you just try adding `gsub` to strip whitespace? i.e. `write.table(gsub(" ", "", Data_Table), ...)`

Comment: Great! it did work indeed! Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gsub` to strip whitespaces when writing the file, i.e.

```
write.table(gsub(" ", "", Data_Table), ...)
```

Comment: THANKS!!!  I try to upvote but I have just signed up, so I need some reputation points to do that :-)

Answer (score 0):

As you want to write a csv-file, maybe try write.csv. For me it worked, when openening it in Excel.

```
,"datestring","ID","UOM","field_output"
1,20160831,1,"kWh",100628610
2,20160831,2,"kWh",1800000
3,20160831,3,"kWh",252
4,20160831,4,"kWh",0
5,20160831,5,"kWh",0
```

During the trial it added a extra line of id's with reading in by setting **row.names=ID** I could have avoided it or by setting **row.names=FALSE** in the write.csv() function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem is I would like a csv with semicolon separator instead of comma - hence the use of write.table

Comment: Sorry, I just realized it is not possible to change this you are rigth.